# Tool for reading values from the chart

Tags: data-visualization

I am given a paper with Kaplan-Meier curve. I'd like "reverse-engineer" the chart to get the original data (without the censoring events, as they are difficult to discern in my low quality copy).

I've seen the tool for this task on the Net, but it was long time ago and  forgot its name.

Can someone please remind me, how to find it?

Thanks.

Comment: Not enough information - is anything unique about this type of figure not covered by tools in this question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14437/software-needed-to-scrape-data-from-graph?

Comment: @David Yes, exactly. I just didn't come up with the word "scrape", so probably that's why I didn't find it. I think it is safe to close this question as a duplicate. Do not delete it, so it would be easier for other people to find the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about [DataThief](http://www.datathief.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [digitize package](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=594) for R.