# Standards on presenting graphs and charts in vector format?

Tags: data-visualization, reproducible-research, presentation

In his up-voted answer to *[Software needed to scrape data from graph](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14437/software-needed-to-scrape-data-from-graph/72974)*, [Alexey](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/25283/alexey-popkov) writes (with respect to the need for data scraping off of raster graphs) "But nowadays the good practice is to publish graphs in vector form."

To rip off my comment to Alexey from that page: **Is there a good reference for best practices around which vector format(s) to present graphs of data in?** For example, ought I use an [eps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulated_PostScript) encapsulation of an [svg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) file in my [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) manuscripts, or am I supposed to [output graph in LaTeX directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979097/best-way-to-draw-a-bar-chart-in-latex)? Or something else?

Answer (score 3):

Or make your data and code available using R, [ggplot2](http://ggplot2.org/) and [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) so it is fully reproducible. And then you can use the gridSVG package to create SVG versions of the ggplot2 plots.

Comment: Making data and code available (I try to do both) does not really address the question, which was specifically about vector format graphs and charts.

Comment: It would be if you then also used the gridSVG package to create SVG versions of the ggplot2 plots

Comment: GREAT! How about you edit your answer to make that more explicit, and possibly offer a link or two to the requested "best practices" or guidelines? Or create a how-to right here. :)