# Forecasting a time series based on a collection of other time series

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I am new to Time Series analysis, but I read a lot of questions here which deal with how you can forecast values of a time series based on its history alone.

Now, the data I have is of this kind :

TimeSeries1:

```
timestamp value
..        ..
..        ..
```

Now, I have a huge number of other timeseries, which follow the same schema.
Also the data is not seasonal. If plotted, the time series will look like a rectangular wave.

What I want to do is forecast values of TimeSeries1, based on the aggregate behavior of all the remaining timeseries data that I have. I had a look at this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14351/forecasting-time-series-based-on-a-behavior-of-other-one), but my problem involves incorporating a large number of other time-series rather than just one like in the above question.

What are the possible approaches to this problem?

Comment: Have you got a good idea of the underlying behavior of the process that generates your multiple observed time series? Do you know that there is a common process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should check if the time series you want to forecast is Granger-Caused by your other variables, if it is, it makes sense to fit a VAR(vector autoregression)-model. In a VAR your dependent variable regress on lagged values of itself and the  other variables as well. Might this be what you are looking for?

Comment: These concepts and keywords helped me get a good start. Thanks. I'll report back here if I make progress.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is an automated process for analysing the available information and selecting the best model out of a list of all possible models. If so, you might want to a software refered to as [LDT](https://sourceforge.net/projects/letdatalk/). I should mension that it (currently) searches a subspace of stationary VAR models.

disclaimer: I am its developer.